# c++ - Use of header/source files to separate interface and implementation

Tags: c++

In C++, classes are usually declared like this:

```
// Object.h

class Object
{
    void doSomething();
}

// Object.cpp

#include "Object.h"

void Object::doSomething()
{
    // do something
}
```

I understand that this improves compile time because having the class in one file makes you recompile it whenever you change either the implementation or the interface (see [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/48857/ways-to-organize-interface-and-implementation-in-c)).

However, from and OOP point of view, I don't see how separating the interface from the implementation helps. I've read a lot of other questions and answers, but the problem I have is that if you define the methods for a class properly (in separate header/source files), then how can you make a different implementation? If you define Object::method in two different places, then how will the compiler know which one to call? Do you declare the Object::method definitions in different namespaces?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *However, from [an] OOP point of view, I don't see how separating the interface from the implementation helps.*

It doesn't help **from an OOP point of view**, and isn't intended to. This is a text inclusion feature of C++ which is inherited from C, a language that has no direct support for object-oriented programming.

Text inclusion for modularity is a feature borrowed, in turn, from assembly languages. It is almost an antithesis to object-oriented programming or basically anything that is good in the area of computer program organization.

Text inclusion allows your C++ compiler to interoperate with ancient object file formats which do not store any type information about symbols. The `Object.cpp` file is compiled to this object format, resulting in an `Object.o` file or `Object.obj` or what have you on your platform. When other parts of the program use this module, they almost solely trust the information that is written about it in `Object.h`. Nothing useful emanates out of the `Object.o` file except for symbols accompanied by numeric information like their offsets and sizes. If the information in the header  doesn't correctly reflect `Object.obj`, you have undefined behavior (mitigated, in some cases, by C++'s support for function overloading, which turns mismatched function calls into unresolving symbols, thanks to name mangling).

For instance if the header declares a variable `extern int foo;` but the object file is the result of compiling `double foo = 0.0;` it means that the rest of the program is accessing a `double` object as an `int`. What prevents this from happening is that `Object.cpp` includes its own header (thereby forcing the mismatch between the declaration and definition to be caught by the compiler) and that you have a sane build system in place which ensures that `Object.cpp` is rebuilt if anything touches `Object.h`.  If that check is based on timestamps, you must also have a sane file system and version control system that don't do wacky things with timestamps.

Answer (score 3):

If you want one interface and multiple implementations in the same program then you use an abstract virtual base.

Like so:

```
class Printer {
    public:
    virtual void print_string(const char *s) = 0;
    virtual ~Printer();
};
```

Then you can have implementations:

```
class EpsonPrinter : public Printer {
    public:
    void print_string(const char *s) override;
};

class LexmarkPrinter : public Printer {
     public:
     void print_string(const char *s) override;
};
```

On the other hand, if you are looking at code which implements OS independence, it might have several subdirectories, one for each OS. The header files are the same, but the source files for Windows are only built for Windows and the source files for Linux/POSIX are only built for Linux.

Answer (score 1):

> If you define Object::method in two different places, then how will the compiler know which one to call?

It won't, and in fact you will be breaking the "One Definition Rule" if you do this, which results in undefined behavior, no diagnostic required, according to the standards.

If you want to define multiple implementations for a class interface, you should use inheritance in some way.

One way that you might do it is, use a virtual base class and override some of the methods in different subclasses.

If you want to manipulate instances of the class as value types, then you can use the pImpl idiom, combined with virtual inheritance. So you would have one class, the "pointer" class, which exposes the interface, and holds a pointer to an abstract virtual base class type. Then, in the .cpp file, you would define the virtual base class, and define multiple subclasses of it, and different constructors of the pImpl class would instantiate different of the subclasses as the implementation.

If you want to use *static* polymorphism, rather than run-time polymorphism, you can use the CRTP idiom (which is still ultimately based on inheritance, just not virtual inheritance).